# How do I append a variable to another variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I can't find the answer using Google.

Works!

```
i = 15
appended = "Dark " << "Silk"
appended = appended
```

Doesn't work. :(

```
i = 15
appended = "Dark " << i
appended = appended
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a proper error description.

Comment: `appended = "Dark " << i.to_s`

Comment: checkout http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/String/%3C%3C `If the object is a Integer, it is considered as a codepoint, and is converted to a character before concatenation.`

Comment: Here is a gif animation where I show it not working. http://i.imm.io/tZ6l.gif

Comment: appended = appended is redundant. You already set the variable.

Comment: Where can I find some good documentations for Ruby? The Ruby-lang official one is more tutorial structured than a reference. Is there any useful ones that you keep referring back to, now and again?

Comment: The example I saw on the internet @lardawge told me to do it. I was going to remove the final line afterwards, once I saw that it worked.

Comment: Ah, finally I saw it. The title changing.

Comment: Most installations (if not all) come with a book about Ruby. `/Ruby192/doc/bookofruby.pdf` for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
i = 15
appended = "Dark " + "Silk"
```

or for non-`String` objects:

```
appended = "Dark " + i.to_s
```

You can also use string interpolation (which is more idiomatic):

```
appended = "Dark #{i}"
```

Comment: Where can I find some good documentations for Ruby? The Ruby-lang official one is ridiculous as I looked up _variables_ and there wasn't much information on it. Is there any useful ones that you keep referring back to, now and again?

Comment: Ruby-doc: http://ruby-doc.org/
However for things like string interpolation which aren't really something you'd know about without reading other Ruby code, I'd recommend just occasionally reading production Ruby code written by other people to learn tricks like that.

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
"Dark" << i.to_s
```

do what you want?

Comment: The long explanation here is that Ruby does not generally convert types like other languages such as JavaScript do.

Comment: Right. For example 1 + '1' is valid in javascript, but yields '11' which might not be what you want. So ruby shouts at you if you try to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`"Silk"` is a string and `15` is an integer. You can ONLY concatenate and string to another string. That's why `"Dark" << "Silk"` works.
If you first transform `15` into a string with `15.to_s`, you'll be able to concatenate it.

I suggest you read through [Ruby's documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) to find out more about built-in classes and methods.

Comment: I looked up the word _variable_ on the page, and the only matches that came up were `class_variables` methods. How can a documentation not teach me how to set a variable? No wonder I had to ask this question.

Comment: That was the languages reference, not a tutorial.
Ruby documentation is very clear and helpful. Should you want to learn how to start programming in Ruby, there are a number of tutorials around the internet. Try out [Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/).

Comment: I searched the site and I can find it now. http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html It's just weird how a **reference** doesn't teach me how to set a **variable**. Even the C and Processing.js reference teaches me how to do _that!_ This is just ridiculous! I thought about reading the tutorial books on the Ruby language, but instead I've decided to dive right in coding with the Ramaze framework and learn as I go along, like I did before with other languages.

Comment: A **reference** is meant to be used as **reference** by people who **already** know the language's basics, not as a tutorial.
Besides, what you are trying to do is **not** set a variable, but call instance methods with parameters, although you probably haven't noticed this.

Comment: I must be doing it wrong because I use references _as_ a substitute for tutorials, once I have a small patch of code to start off from. It worked for me in other languages.

Comment: Some references eventually present tutorial sections, but that's the exception. As a COMPLETE guide to the expected behaviour of built-in classes and modules, Ruby's is just fine.
Don't blame Ruby's documentation for being what it should be.